# JQuery Nested Tab - not first child is selected on click of parent tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, nested, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I have created nested tabs. The sample end structure is like below : 
Note: "The "_1"'s are added dynamically using foreach. So all the child div's are created dynamically using the server returned values."

```
    <div id="tabs">

      <ul id="tablinks">
      <li><a href="#childtab_1">First Parent</a></li>
      <li><a href="#childtab_2">Second Parent</a></li>
      </ul>


    <div id="childtab_1">
       <div id="ct_1">
        <ul id="childTabLinks_1">
        <li><a href="#childtabs-11">First Nested Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#childtabs-12">Second Nested Tab</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="childtabs-11"><p>First child content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="childtabs-12"><p>Second child content</p>
        </div>
    </div>   

    <div id="childtab_2">   
    .
    .
    </div> 

    In Java Script:   
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    $('#childtabs_1').tabs(
    //getting data using ajaxOptions
    );
    $('#childtabs_2').tabs(
    //getting data using ajaxOptions
    );
```

Consider that under parent 1 - second child is clicked. If i click parent 2 and then come back to parent 1, second child is still selected. I want the first child should be selected whenever a parent tab is clicked.

I read through other posts - and tried using

1. click function on anchor element. 
       like

   ```
   $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){
      var parent = $('#tabs').tabs();
      $parent.tabs('select',0);
   });
   ```

   Its not working.
2. Tried using bind on tabselect. Its causing eventbubble and also not working.

   ```
   $('#tabs').bind(
           'tabsselect', 
           function(event, ui) {
               $("#tabLinks li a").on("click", function () { 
                   $('#childTabLinks_0 li a').first().trigger("click"); 
               });     
           }
   );
   ```

Please share if there is a solution to have the first child selected automatically whenever a parent is selected.

Comment: $parent is not declared any where , you only declared parent as variable.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need the click function inside the tabselect function:

```
$('#tabs').bind(
    'tabsselect',
        function() {
            $(this).children('.child-tabs').tabs('select',0);
        }
    }
); 

<div id="childtab_1">
   <div id="ct_1">
      <ul id="childTabLinks_1" class="child-tabs">
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I missed to say this - The "_1"'s are added dynamically using foreach. So all the child div's are created dynamically using the server returned values. This ' class="child-tabs" ' cannot be added just to identify the first child. 1. I tried with class ".child-tabs" as given - and it didnt work. 2. I updated it and tried with div wild card - didnt work.          

         $('#tabs').tabs({
     select: function(event, ui) {
 $('#tabs').children("[id^=ct_]").tabs('select',0); 
     }
 });

Comment: 3. Also doing a bind on tabselect - is causing event bubble. Such that, if you click on a child - the event is bubbled to parent and the code inside the bind is executing. Although my issue still persist. Doing by pt-2 - mentioning it during tab intialization itself is not doing event bubble.